# How to undo system reset Windows 8

Tags: windows, reset

I hit the reset link instead of restore by mistake, is there any way to recover the files deleted through this, or to undo the reset?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you quick formatted the drive, you can use programs like Recuva to scan for file data.

http://www.piriform.com/recuva

The best Linux utility is TestDisk.